# Jquery Scroll to Div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to scroll down when the image is clicked (a class = 'scrollTo) , down to the next div (second-container). I tried searching and couldn't find a fix that worked.Everytime I try the page just refreshed when I click.  Here is the code and thank you in advanced for the help.

```
  <div class='layer_two'>
    <a class="scrollTo" href=""><img src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/trico-arrows-1/24/TriangleDown-512.png' />
  </div>  

   <div class='second-container'>
    <div class='special'>
        <h2>Turn ordinary into extraordinary</h2>
        <div class='border'>

        </div>
```

jquery

```
$(".scrollTo").click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".second-container").offset().top},
    'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".scrollTo").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".second-container").offset().top},
        'slow');
    });
}
```

Try the above.

The above should prevent the default behavior of the click action on the link.
you could do the same by finishing your listener with a "return false".
In both cases it tells the browser "dont execute the built in behavior of this event, only execute my listener"

by default the browser executes both your listener and is default listener (in this case, linking to a page)

Comment: For reference, see [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Comment: Thanks. Added more as you commented. I wanted to make sure the answer was up before I tried to put an explanation in. sometimes it takes me a bit to find the words to explain the situation without glossing too much or getting redundant...